# Список словарей затирается

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
mob = [
    {"last_name": "Petrov", "first_name": "Oleg", "phone": "46546546465", "age": "4"},
    {"last_name": "Ivanov", "first_name": "Petr", "phone": "34534534534", "age": "5"},
    {"last_name": "Metrov", "first_name": "Mikl", "phone": "56456456466", "age": "6"},
    {"last_name": "HHHHHH", "first_name": "Manr", "phone": "77777777777", "age": "7"},
    {"last_name": "PPPPPP", "first_name": "Give", "phone": "64563426888", "age": "8"},
    {"last_name": "TTTTTT", "first_name": "Lisa", "phone": "66666666666", "age": "9"}
]
peple = {}
peples = []

for i in mob:
    peple["last_name"] = i['last_name']
    peple["phones"] = ['phones']
    peple["age"] = i['age']

    peples.append(peple)


print(peples)
```

почему весь список `peples[]` заполняется последним значение из списка `mob[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная `peple` является ссылкой на объект в памяти. Т.е. внутри списка `peples` хранятся ссылки на один и тот же объект. Таким образом на каждой итерации при вызове

```
peple["last_name"] = i['last_name']
peple["phones"] = ['phones']
peple["age"] = i['age']
```

Изменяя значения словаря `peple`, мы изменяем также и те значения, которые уже были добавлены в массив `peples`. Для решения проблемы можно объявить словарь внутри цикла:

```
for i in mob:
    peple = {}
    peple["last_name"] = i['last_name']
    peple["phones"] = ['phones']
    peple["age"] = i['age']

    peples.append(peple)
```

Проверить то, в массиве хранятся ссылки на один и тот же объект можно при помощи функции `id`, которая возвращает идентификатор объекта. Для приведённого вами кода:

```
peples = []
peple = {}
for i in mob:
    peple["last_name"] = i['last_name']
    peple["phones"] = ['phones']
    peple["age"] = i['age']

    peples.append(peple)
    print(id(peple))
```

Вывод:

```
47920208
47920208
47920208
47920208
47920208
47920208
```

В случае, если мы определим словарь `peple` внутри цикла:

```
peples = []

for i in mob:
    peple = {}
    peple["last_name"] = i['last_name']
    peple["phones"] = ['phones']
    peple["age"] = i['age']

    peples.append(peple)
    print(id(peple))
```

Вывод:

```
47985792
48167744
48167792
48167840
48167888
48167936
```

Видно, что идентификаторы всех объектов в первом случае одинаковы, во втором случае -- нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [23]: import operator

In [24]: keys = "last_name", "phone", "age"

In [25]: items = operator.itemgetter(*keys)

In [26]: mob = [
    ...:     {"last_name": "Petrov", "first_name": "Oleg", "phone": "46546546465", "age": "4"},
    ...:     {"last_name": "Ivanov", "first_name": "Petr", "phone": "34534534534", "age": "5"},
    ...:     {"last_name": "Metrov", "first_name": "Mikl", "phone": "56456456466", "age": "6"},
    ...:     {"last_name": "HHHHHH", "first_name": "Manr", "phone": "77777777777", "age": "7"},
    ...:     {"last_name": "PPPPPP", "first_name": "Give", "phone": "64563426888", "age": "8"},
    ...:     {"last_name": "TTTTTT", "first_name": "Lisa", "phone": "66666666666", "age": "9"}
    ...: ]

In [27]: [dict(zip(keys, items(item))) for item in mob]
Out[27]:
[{'last_name': 'Petrov', 'phone': '46546546465', 'age': '4'},
 {'last_name': 'Ivanov', 'phone': '34534534534', 'age': '5'},
 {'last_name': 'Metrov', 'phone': '56456456466', 'age': '6'},
 {'last_name': 'HHHHHH', 'phone': '77777777777', 'age': '7'},
 {'last_name': 'PPPPPP', 'phone': '64563426888', 'age': '8'},
 {'last_name': 'TTTTTT', 'phone': '66666666666', 'age': '9'}]
```

Вот хорошая статья про мутабельность типов https://medium.com/@Cu7ious/python-mutable-vs-immutable-ae9a188effe3.